# How to add a shortcut to an individual iBook file to the iPad home screen?

Tags: ipad, books

I'm currently in the process of creating an iBook for use within my company. Some of the people who will be using it aren't particularly tech-savvy, so I want to make it as easy as possible for them to access the iBook directly from the home screen of their iPads. I don't want them to have to worry about navigating into the iBooks app at all. Is there any way to save the individual iBook file directly to the home screen?

Answer (score 1):

1. Host your epub somewhere, preferable direct link to open the epub itself. Eg. https://epub-samples.googlecode.com/files/mymedia_lite-20130621.epub
2. From the address bar, select the **Share** icon and add it to Home Screen, rename it to your epub name.

When they open the URL, they'll see options to open epub in supported app, with **Open in iBooks** on the right button.

The first time they open the epub, it'll be imported to iBooks, open them in iBooks. After that, choosing the same option will open the same epub, preventing duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You're mostly correct but the problem is that the home screen Web Clip (aka bookmark) will forever point to the URL. The user will always get asked whether they want to open in iBooks so it's a bit of a clunky solution if you ask me.

If it were me, I'd be considering the following options:

1. Deploy the content using an MDM like Airwatch, specifically its Content Locker feature. It also manages updates to content very well.
2. Publish your content online (in HTML) and deploy the icon pointing to your URL as a Web Clip app.
3. Publish your content officially as an iBook using Apple Xcode. Pretty high end solution though and will require an Apple developer account.