# Home screen shortcut to interactive PDF

Tags: ipad, pdf

I have a locally stored interactive PDF (with a navigation including hyperlinks to other pages) on iPad.  I'm able to open from files or books and view it interactively but, is it possible to create a shortcut with custom icon and place it on the home screen as if it were an app?  I know this is possible with URLs but I need it to be available without connection so it can't be anything on the cloud.

I have read answers to similar questions here but those are very old solutions that either require a connection or don't seem to be valid anymore.

Comment: Which answers did you look at, specifically which don't seem to be valid anymore?

Comment: The second option in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273971/9058 seems to be still useable

Comment: Thank you @nohillside That is one of the solutions I looked at but that one stores the file in iCloud.  I will be using it on a place without connection.

Comment: also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131555/

Comment: You should be able to use the same approach with files stored within "On my iPad".